# Add <br> button in WYGWAM toolbar

Tags: wygwam

Is there a way to add a button to the WYGWAM styles or controls that allows user to easily insert a `<br>` tag inside a paragraph?

Comment: Yes, that works great. If you want to include as an answer I'm more than happy to vote that up as an accepted answer. Also, I was able to find this included in CKEditor documentation along with other useful shortcuts: [links](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shift-enter is easy enough. Hoop it helps